# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars + Solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, spyder

According to Python Documentation a TypeError is defined as

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.
>   [exception TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)

The reason I got this Error was because my code looked like this:

```
import math as m
import pylab as pyl
import numpy as np

#normal distribution function
def normal(x,mu,sigma):
    P=(1/(m.sqrt(2*m.pi*sigma**2)))*(m.exp((-(x-mu)**2)/2*sigma**2))
    return P

#solution
x = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
P = normal(x,0,1)
#plotting the function
pyl.plot(x,P)
pyl.show()
```

P=(1/(**m**.sqrt(2***m**.pi*sigma**2)))***(**m.exp((-(x-mu)**2)/2*sigma**2))
Notice the m. - This is incorrect, because math. can only handle scalars. And the Error said that a **TypeError** had occurred.
np. (Numpy) can handle scalers as well as arrays and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The right code looks like this:

```
import math as m
import pylab as pyl
import numpy as np

# normal distribution function
def normal(x,mu,sigma):
    P = (1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2))) * (np.exp((-(x-mu)**2)/2*sigma**2))
    return P

# solution
x = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
P = normal(x,0,1)
# plotting the function
pyl.plot(x,P)
pyl.show()
```

In the end we get a great normal distribution function that looks like this:
[image: normaldistribution]

This Error occurred in Spyder IDE.